# How to switch adb from wifi to usb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have installed adb Wi-Fi plugin in my android studio which works fine when device is connected over same wi-fi connection. But, if when I try to run on another device from usb connected with other wi-fi it shows my device Offline.
I found that adb has switched from usb to wi-fi.

I have tried to restart studio but problem remains same.

I have also tried `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` but nothing changed.

How can I switch back from wi-fi to usb?

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
DE6DIFK7R8S475H6    offline
```

Answer (score 4):

Connect your phone through usb

At terminal:

```
adb kill-server
adb usb
```